# Wireless interface works after reboot or suspend and then dissconnects

Tags: wifi

a few hours ago I installed Elementary OS in a computer, everything was ok until I connected to my wi-fi and a few minutes after I got a disconnect notification from the network manager. I restarted the computer and again, my wi-fi was working fine but suddenly it got disconnected then I suspended the computer and wi-fi start working after unlocking the computer but a couple of minutes after it stopped.

I have checked another blogs and communities about this, but I have not find anything helpful (Or I haven't look up right). Can I do something to fix this situation?. Thanks.

Here are the specs of my wireless card:

```
 $ lspci -k
02:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT5390R 802.11bgn PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RT5390R 802.11bgn PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
    Kernel modules: rt2800pci, wl
```

Here is the `# ip link show wlp2s0` result **when the wireless was working**:

```
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:76:3f:83:99:af brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

And here is the same command **when the wireless stopped working**:

```
3: wlp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:76:3f:83:99:af brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a conflicting driver module the `rt2800pci` and `wl` . Unload the `wl` module:

```
sudo rmmod wl
```